# Adding an LED through a FET circuit that currently drives a solenoid

Tags: transistors, mosfet, solenoid, snubber

I would like to save space on a layout by consolidating a FET or two, where feasible, on an existing board. One of the FETs used, a coolMOS P7 series (IPA60R280P7SXKSA1), seems to have the drain current availability and the acceptable logic to combine its existing solenoid drive function to also include a green LED.

Factoring in the flyback diodes/magnetic field collapse aspect of the solenoid, would it be a poor design practice to put an LED in parallel? If so, why?

Thanks

[image: FET]

Comment: Without a resistor in series with the LED, yes it would be poor practice. See any number of questions regarding driving LEDs for why.

Comment: Thanks, Brian. I failed to mention that the LED (diode on the right) is part of an LED strip product whose length is cut not to exceed the continuous drain current of the FET.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add reference designators to each component.

Assuming the diode on the right is the LED, adding a current limiting resistor in series with it should be all you need.  The series combination of the LED and its resistor is in parallel with the solenoid coil and the flyback suppression diode.

Comment: Thank you. Sorry for lacking labels. Since I can't seem to upload a new picture, we'll call snubber on the left 'D1', LED on the right 'D2', and solenoid L1.